# Not getting the output I'm looking for in program, also having trouble with a user input equaling a string loop

Tags: java, arrays, file, methods, user-input

My code is done and working for the most part, this is what i have

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Proj5 {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("results.txt"));
    int [] quizKey = {1,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,4,1,3,5,4,1,2};
    String [] userAnswers = new String[100];
    String [] wid = new String[100];
    int [] numCorrect = new int[quizKey.length];

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
    int max;
    int min;

    int lines=0;
    readInText(s);
    s = readInText(s);
    while(s.hasNext()){
        String line = s.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        wid[lines] = tokens[0];
        userAnswers[lines] = tokens[1];
        lines ++;

    }// end while loop
    long[][] userAnswersInt = new long[lines][quizKey.length];
    numCorrect = gradeSingleQuiz(lines, quizKey, userAnswers, numCorrect, userAnswersInt);
    double[] percentCorrect = new double[lines];
    percentCorrect = percentCorrect(lines, numCorrect, numCorrect);
    char[] grades = new char[lines];
    grades = grade(numCorrect, lines);
    max=max(numCorrect);
    min=min(numCorrect);

    displayOutput(outFile, wid, lines, numCorrect, grades, percentCorrect);
    averageScore(outFile, max, min, lines, percentCorrect);
}//end main



public static Scanner readInText(Scanner s)throws IOException{
    /*String input;
    System.out.print("Enter name of the file: ");
    input=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(input);
    while(input!="QuizScores.txt"){
        System.out.println("invalid file entered, please enter the correct anem of the file: ");
        input=s.nextLine();
    }
    */
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("QuizScores.txt"));

    return inFile;


}// end readInText

public static String[] userAnswers(String userAnswers[]){
    return userAnswers;
}
/**
 * calculates the grades of the tests
 * 
 * @param lines - number of 
 * @param quizKey - answers to the test
 * @param userAnswers - string version of user answers
 * @param numCorrect - number of answers correct
 * @param userAnswersInt - int version of user answers
 * @return numCorrect - number of answers correct
 */
public static int[] gradeSingleQuiz(int lines, int quizKey[], String userAnswers[], int numCorrect[], long userAnswersInt[][]){
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){
    numCorrect[j]=0;
        long[] ara = new long[quizKey.length];
        ara [j] = Long.parseLong(userAnswers[j]);
        for(int p=0; p<ara.length; p++){
            userAnswersInt[j][p]=ara[j]%10;
            ara[j]=ara[j]/10;
        }
        int rows = userAnswersInt.length;
            int cols = userAnswersInt[0].length;
            long[][] userAnswersReverse = new long[rows][cols];
        if(j==4){
            for(int q=0; q<userAnswersInt.length;q++){
            for(int w = cols-1; w >=0; w--){
                userAnswersReverse[q][cols-1-w] = userAnswersInt[q][w];
                }
            }
        }
        if(j==4){
            for(int r=0; r<lines; r++){
                for(int n=0; n<quizKey.length; n++){
                    System.out.println(userAnswersReverse[r][n]);
                    if(userAnswersReverse[r][n]==(quizKey[n])){
                    numCorrect[r]++;    
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }//end for loop

return numCorrect;
}// end gradeSingleQuiz
/**
 * calculates the max
 * 
 * @param numCorrect - number of correct answers
 * @return max - the highest number of correct answers
 */
public static int max(int numCorrect[]){
    int max = numCorrect[0];
    for(int r=0; r<numCorrect.length; r++){
        if(numCorrect[r]>max){
            max=numCorrect[r];
        }
    }
return max;
}
/**
 * calculates the min
 * 
 * @param numCorrect - number of correct answers
 * @return min - the lowest number of correct answers
 */
public static int min(int numCorrect[]){
    int min = numCorrect[0];
    for(int r=0; r<numCorrect.length; r++){
        if(numCorrect[r]<min){
            min=numCorrect[r];
        }
    }
return min;
}
/**
* grade of the test
*
* @param numCorrect - number of answers correct
* @param lines - number of lines in file
* @return grade - the letter grade is being returned)
*/
public static char[] grade(int numCorrect[], int lines){
    char[] grade = new char[lines];
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){


if(numCorrect[j]>=14)
            grade[j]='A';
        else if((numCorrect[j]>=12)&&(numCorrect[j]<14))
            grade[j]='B';
        else if((numCorrect[j]>=11)&&(numCorrect[j]<12))
            grade[j]='C';
        else if ((numCorrect[j]>=9)&&(numCorrect[j]<11))
            grade[j]='D';
        else
            grade[j]='F';
    }
    return grade;
}//end grade
/**
 * percent of the answers correct
 * 
 * @param lines - number of lines in file
 * @param numCorrect - number of answers correct
 * @param quizKey - correct answers
 * @return centCorrect - percent of correct answers (1)
 */
public static double[] percentCorrect(int lines, int numCorrect[], int quizKey[]){
    double[] centCorrect = new double[lines];
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){
    centCorrect[j] = (numCorrect[j]/quizKey.length)*100;
    }
return centCorrect;
}
/**
 * average of all the test scores & displays min and max
 * 
 * @param min - lowest score
 * @param max - highest score
 * @param lines - number of lines in file
 * @param percentCorrect - percent of correct answers
 * @return none
 */
public static void averageScore(PrintWriter outFile, int min, int max, int lines, double percentCorrect[]){
    double add=0;
    for(int d=0; d<lines; d++){ 
        add = percentCorrect[d] + add;
    }//end for loop
    add=add/lines;
    System.out.println("Average: " + add + "%");
    outFile.println("Average: " + add + "%");
    System.out.println("High Score: " + max);
    outFile.println("High Score: " + max);
    System.out.println("Low Score: " + min);
    outFile.println("Low Score: " + min);
}// end averageScore
/**
 * displays the student id number correct percent correct and grade
 * 
 * @param wid - wildcat ID
 * @param lines -number of lines in file 
 * @param numCorrect - number of answers correct
 * @param grades - grade of test
 * @param percentCorrect - percent of answers correct
 * @return none
 */
public static void displayOutput( PrintWriter outFile, String wid[], int lines, int numCorrect[], char grades[], double percentCorrect[]){
    System.out.println("Student ID    # Correct    %Correct    Grade");
    outFile.println("Student ID    # Correct    %Correct    Grade");

for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
        System.out.println("  " + wid[i] + "          " + numCorrect[i] + "        " +
                (percentCorrect[i]) + "%" + "      " + grades[i]);  
        outFile.println("  " + wid[i] + "          " + numCorrect[i] + "        " +

(percentCorrect[i]) + "%" + "      " + grades[i]);
    }

}// end display output

}//end class
```

This is the output i get when i don't include the user input requirement:

```
Student ID    # Correct    %Correct    Grade
 4563123          15        100.0%      A
 2312311          9        0.0%      D
 2312345          13        0.0%      B
 5527687          9        0.0%      D
 7867567          6        0.0%      F
Average: 20.0%
High Score: 0
Low Score: 15
```

So I will start with my problems with this, overall it works great, it just for some reason isn't assigning the values to the percentCorrect array (i Think not 100%) additionally the High score (max) and Low Score(min) aren't working correctly and I don't know why this is happening either so help with those things would be awesome, I'm completely stumped on that.

My other problem is this, i need to ask the user to enter the name of the file, and if they enter the incorrect one let them know they did and ask again until they get it right, I implemented This:

```
String input;
    System.out.print("Enter name of the file: ");
    input=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(input);
    while(input!="QuizScores.txt"){
        System.out.println("invalid file entered, please enter the correct anem of the file: ");
        input=s.nextLine();
    }
```

But it doesn't work because even when I enter the correct string (capitols and everything) it still prints the "invalid file etered, please..." line I don't know what I am doing wrong here either, so help with this would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Okay i think the problems may lie with in these blocks of code (again not 100%)

```
percentCorrect = percentCorrect(lines, numCorrect, numCorrect);
```

and/or

```
public static double[] percentCorrect(int lines, int numCorrect[], int quizKey[]){
    double[] centCorrect = new double[lines];
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){
    centCorrect[j] = (numCorrect[j]/quizKey.length)*100;
    }
return centCorrect;
}
```

and/or

```
public static int max(int numCorrect[]){
    int max = numCorrect[0];
    for(int r=0; r<numCorrect.length; r++){
        if(numCorrect[r]>max){
            max=numCorrect[r];
        }
    }
return max;
```

and/or

```
public static int min(int numCorrect[]){
    int min = numCorrect[0];
    for(int r=0; r<numCorrect.length; r++){
        if(numCorrect[r]<min){
            min=numCorrect[r];
        }
    }
return min;
}
```

The file I am pulling from is this:

```
4563123,112211324135412
2312311,222121324135211
2312345,112211324135421
5527687,212111313124412
7867567,111111111111111
```

Comment: Way too much code, you should try to find a way to narrow it down to the problem.

Comment: `if(userAnswersReverse[r][n]==(quizKey[n])){`  Are they `String` instances being compared?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & ask a single question.

Comment: they are not string instances, one is long one is int i was using .equals() but it was giving me an error so i changed it

Comment: @AndrewThompson the problem isnt in that line tho, that line seems to work because its returning the correct values for numCorrect

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the "File entered is not correct" is because of this line `while(input!="QuizScores.txt")`

You cannot check string equalities using "==" or "!=", use the     equals method instead, like so     `input.equals("QuizScores.txt")`

The reason behind this is, using "!=" checks the string objects for reference equality.

Also, in your code, you are calling `readInText()` twice, the first time does nothing.

High score and low score appear incorrect because the method definition of `averageScore()` has min as the second argument and max as the third, when you called it, you swapped min and max.

EDIT:

And the reason %Correct is showing 100% for the first and 0% for the remaining is because of the math in calculating your percentages.

`centCorrect[j] = (numCorrect[j]/quizKey.length)*100` will not work because of the division of integers, resulting in a whole number, which is to say, the decimals are lost.

In order to get the correct values, cast the ints to doubles like so

`centCorrect[j] = ((double)numCorrect[j]/(double)quizKey.length)*100`

Comment: Okay thank you that fixed my min and max values i actually did not realize that they had to be an order in which you called the arguments, I'm surprised nothing else messed up in regards to that, but do you have any suggestions on how i could check to see if the two strings are equal??